# Что означают союзы в данном предложении?

Tags: союзы, смысл

Лица, награжденные орденами или медалями, либо удостоенные почетных званий СССР или Российской Федерации, либо награжденные ведомственными знаками отличия в труде и имеющие трудовой стаж не менее 20 лет для женщин и 25 лет для мужчин или стаж, необходимый для назначения пенсии за выслугу лет; лица, начавшие трудовую деятельность в несовершеннолетнем возрасте в период Великой Отечественной войны и имеющие трудовой стаж не менее 40 лет для мужчин и 35 лет для женщин.

Answer (score 1):

"Или" и "либо" – здесь синонимы. Чередуются они только для того, чтобы фраза легче читалась. Оба означают ровно то же, что и операция "или" (V) в математической логике. A V B – означает, что истинным является либо только А, либо только B, либо оба вместе.
А союз И означает то же, что операция "и" в матлогике.  То есть, как в любом юридическом документе, разных толкований быть не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Из статьи [О значениях союзов *или* и *либо*](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/view/0/?*=SCJ11V1saQDs%2F3J1JH049K8k%2Bn97InVybCI6InlhLWRpc2stcHVibGljOi8vcWdUV2U4MlJJNEJLWU16TTlMM0xyYzA3bnJEc0oybFJYamp1Qmd0UG1ldz0iLCJ0aXRsZSI6Ilphdl9QUF8yMDA4LnBkZiIsInVpZCI6IjAiLCJ5dSI6IjY5MzUwNzEyMzE1MDQ0MjY0MTgiLCJub2lmcmFtZSI6ZmFsc2UsInRzIjoxNTM5NDIxMjY5Njk0fQ%3D%3D&page=1):
В “Грамматике русского языка” отмечалось:
“Сложносочиненные предложения с союзом **либо** (одиночным или повторяющимся) по своим структурным особенностям и по общему значению полностью совпадают со сложносочиненными предложени­ями с союзом **или**”.
...они являются настолько синонимичными, что в по­
давляющем большинстве контекстов могут взаимозаменяться, а то и употребляться в общем сочинительном ряду:
*“В лагере всегда так: **или** жить не дают, **либо** ничего не видят и не знают”* (Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей); *“Если сейчас объявится законный наследник дона Мигеля де Перальты, США придется **либо** пожертвовать в его пользу часть своей территории **или** же откупиться”* (Глебов. Аризона в наследство // Веч. Москва. 2002.18 июля).

Разложим все по бюрократическим полкам.
I. 1. Первая группа лиц, имеющих право на что-то:
 - лица, награжденные орденами;
 - лица, награжденные медалями;
 - лица, награжденные орденами и медалями;
 - лица, удостоенные почетных званий;
 - лица, награжденные ведомственными знаками отличия в труде.

Эти награды, звания и знаки должны быть получены в СССР или в РФ.
Если кто-то попадает хотя бы в одну из указанных категорий, то далее уже рассматривается вопрос о необходимом стаже.

II. Во вторую группу могут попасть только лица, рожденные в период с 22 июня 1923 по 9 мая 1927 года.

Answer (score 1):

Я "по полочкам" разложу так.

(1.А)лица, награжденные орденами или медалями,
(1.Б)либо удостоенные почетных званий СССР или Российской Федерации, 
(1.В)либо награжденные ведомственными знаками отличия в труде и имеющие трудовой стаж не менее 20 лет для женщин и 25 лет для мужчин или стаж, необходимый для назначения пенсии за выслугу лет;

(2)лица, начавшие трудовую деятельность в несовершеннолетнем возрасте в период Великой Отечественной войны и имеющие трудовой стаж не менее 40 лет для мужчин и 35 лет для женщин.

Общее условие выполнено если выполнено хотя бы одно из составляяющих частных условий (1.А, 1.Б, 1.В, 2)

Тут просто трудно представить иное... "Или" везде внутри группы "либо".

Правда в отношении 1.В может возникнуть маленькое недоразумение. Там есть "и" и" или".
И трудно без дополнительных соображений понять, как эта конструкция устроена.

Варианта два.

i).
*(a) награжденные ведомственными знаками отличия в труде

и

(b)

  имеющие трудовой стаж не менее 20 лет для женщин и 25 лет для мужчин

  или

  стаж, необходимый для назначения пенсии за выслугу лет*

То есть должно выполняться (a) **и** хотя бы одно из b1 и b2

ii).
*(a) награжденные ведомственными знаками отличия в труде и имеющие трудовой стаж не менее 20 лет для женщин и 25 лет для мужчин

или

(b)  стаж, необходимый для назначения пенсии за выслугу лет*

То есть должно выполняться любое из условий (a) или (b).

Однако, если посмотреть на общий смысл, вариант (ii) отпадает сам собой.

Answer (score -3):

союз ИЛИ означает, что или первая часть предложения (до союза ИЛИ) или вторая часть предложения (после союза ИЛИ)

Comment: Ну неправда, ребята!!! Союз "ИЛИ" делит предложение на две части: 1. Первая группа лиц, имеющих право на что-то:
- лица, награжденные орденами;
- лица, награжденные медалями;
- лица, награжденные орденами и медалями;
- лица, удостоенные почетных званий;
- лица, награжденные ведомственными знаками отличия в труде. Вторая часть - стаж, необходимый для назначения пенсии за выслугу лет; ТОЧКА С ЗАПЯТОЙ. Третья часть - это лица начавшие трудовую деятельность во время ВОВ.

Comment: Сошлитесь на правило в русском языке, что: "Или" и "либо" – здесь синонимы.Союз "ИЛИ" - разделительный союз. Означает или первая часть предложения или вторая часть предложения, как в математике: либо только А, либо только B.

Comment: Ваша трактовка в принципе не противоречит представлениям о грамматике, но здесь она не работает. Союз "или" находится внутри союза "(либо)... либо... либо". Так обычно и поступают в случаях вложенности групп союзов "либо". Добавлю еще, что текст далек от математического, поэтому отсылки к математической логике здесь не работают, как и вообще формальные подходы. А если вчитаться и понять смысл, то вопросов не остается. Остальное - в тексте ответов.

Comment: Спасибо behemothus@mail.ru за исчерпывающий ответ. Он меня устраивает. Низкий поклон. С ув. Александр Кочкин.